# Calculator: Get total sum from single input

Tags: jquery, calculator, jquery-calculation

I'm currently building my first calculator in jQuery and I have some problems with the total sum of the value in the input. I'm not using more than one input because I want to keep it simple and easy to use. The code below prints `NaN` and I don't understand why.

```
$('body').on('click', '#method-getsum', function() {
    var sum = 0;
    var string = $('input[name="fieldtext-calculate"]').val();

    if(string.length != 0) {
        sum += Number(string);
    }

    alert(sum);
});
```

Have I missed something? You can see it all in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/edgren/QTjWR/ (this demo contains the correct solution with the `eval` function (my calculator is not for real project. Just with "play around" project))

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you input something like `1+2`, your code will then call `Number("1+2")`. That's incorrect, since `Number()` expects single number (not the addition) as its argument.
It will not perform operation parsing and interpretation for you, you must write the code yourself.

If it's just a toy project, use `eval` instead of `Number` (avoid `eval` in real projects, it creates security issues).

Comment: Ah! So that's why I'm getting `NaN` :) But when I am testing `parseInt` it only shows the first number (for example the input have 50+3 and it will then only show 50).

Comment: You want to use `split` or something similar to get it into an array.

Comment: Many thanks :) I know now how I will fix my problem. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

Might be you're using a keyword for a variable name.  Try changing your code to:

```
var fieldText = $('input[name="fieldtext-calculate"]').val();

if(fieldText.length != 0) {
    sum += Number(fieldText );
}
```

**EDIT**
Nevermind, the value that is returned from `$('input[name="fieldtext-calculate"]').val();` is the string '7 + 8 + 9'.  Try getting a distinct value by splitting on the `+` sign to get the numbers into and array then loop through the array.

Comment: I got the same error as before with your possible solution - NaN :(